# How to get time_zone_options_for_select with DST offsets?

Tags: ruby, timezone, dst, activesupport

The ActionView::Helpers::FormOptionsHelper provides the [time_zone_options_for_select](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/time_zone_options_for_select) to get a list of options for a select control that includes all of the timezones with their UTC offset. The problem I'm having is how to get it to display the correct offset for when daylight savings time is in effect?

For instance U.S. Mountain time is usually -7 UTC but during the summer it's effectively -6 UTC. Is there a way to have that list correctly reflect that?

Comment: @stevec - Not sure why you posted a bounty here instead of asking a question, but also please scroll to the bottom of [the timezone tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) and read the section about Rails time zones.  Thanks.

Comment: @stevec - I've added an answer which I believe sufficiently answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### TL;DR

The time zone data you are receiving is "correct" because `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` and `TZInfo::Timezone` instances do not make assumptions about the current date, and therefore applying DST to them doesn't make "sense" in the context of the responsibility of those objects.

You *notice* the problem because the default model for [`time_zone_options_for_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-time_zone_options_for_select), `ActiveSupport::TimeZone`, unfortunately returns the offset string when calling `#to_s`, which, if the location is currently is observing DST, will be incorrect. There is no way to fix the string values generated in the options, or even remove the offset from them.

If this isn't acceptable you'll need to skip on using `time_zone_options_for_select`, and use [`options_for_select`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-options_for_select) instead, and generate the options yourself.

### Some investigation

`time_zone_options_for_select` uses `::ActiveSupport::TimeZone` as the default `model` parameter, so passing it in manually will not change your results. In order to construct options for a select box, that method will construct an array of tuples in the format of `[time_zone.to_s, time_zone.name]`, for the purpose of passing it to the more generic `options_for_select` method. `time_zone`, in this case, is an instance of `::ActiveSupport::TimeZone`.

The important factor here is that this time zone instance object is, conceptually, completely unrelated/divorced from the idea of "the current date". The definition of a time zone (strictly speaking) has nothing to do with the current date. We can confirm this "not using DST" issue like so:

```rb
::ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.find { |tz| tz.name == "Adelaide" }.utc_offset
=> 34200 # 9 hours and 30 minutes, in seconds
```

Adelaide's non-DST time zone is ACST (Australian Central Standard Time) which is GMT+9.5. Currently (as in the time of writing), Adelaide is in DST which means they are on ACDT (Australian Central Daylight Time), which is GMT+10.5.

```rb
::ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.find { |tz| tz.name == "Adelaide" }.now.utc_offset
=> 37800 # 10 hours and 30 minutes, in seconds
```

The crucial difference here is essentially what I've outlined above - the `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` instance is just *not* concerned with the current date. The class itself is a convenience wrapper around a `TZInfo::DataTimezone` instance, which has similar opinions on the current date - none.

If you noticed, in the second code snippet above, we called `#now` on the time zone object before calling `#utc_offset`. This returns an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` instance, which includes information about the time zone, as well as the current date - and therefore we get an offset which reflects the fact that the current date should include the DST offset.

So, the only problem here is that including the UTC offset string in the return value of `#to_s` on `ActiveSupport::TimeZone` instances is sort of misleading in this instance. It's included because it's the "base" UTC offset for that time zone.

Resources:

- [Rails 6.1 `time_zone_options_for_select` implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/914caca2d31bd753f47f9168f2a375921d9e91cc/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/form_options_helper.rb#L575)
- [Related GitHub issue, rails/rails#7297](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7297)
- [Related GitHub pull request, rails/rails#22243](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/22243)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar problem but ended up using this

```
time_zone_select('time_zone', TZInfo::Timezone.us_zones, 
                                     :default => "America/Los_Angeles", 
                                     :model => TZInfo::Timezone
```

Did you find a better solution?